# Missing Android API 14 when importing OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

I am trying to import the OpenCV libraries to a new Android Studio project and I get this error:

```
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-14' in: /home/yrudakou/android-sdks
```

As many accepted answers here suggest I tried to install Android API 14 but I don't know how to do this: I can't find the API 14 item in the SDK manager, I see only API 10 and API 15 available and installed.

[image]

I run Android Studio 1.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

Please suggest how to install API 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the obsolete button to see the API 14

Comment: Thank you very much! I am new in Android development.